# Why are string literals const?

Tags: c++, string, constants, literals

It is known that in C++ string literals are immutable and the result of modifying a string literal is undefined.  For example

```
char * str = "Hello!";
str[1] = 'a';
```

This will bring to an undefined behavior.

Besides that string literals are placed in static memory. So they exists during whole program. I would like to know why do string literals have such properties.

Comment: It won't always be a runtime error, it's undefined behaviour. That means it can do *anything*.

Comment: Because they may be placed in ROM depending on the current linker script.

Comment: this behavior is deprecated in C++03 and banned in C++11.

Comment: @ipc I tried it write this code in Visual Studio 2012 (with new standard of C++), but an error still exist.

Comment: I don't know Visual Studio but if they reach full C++11 conformity, this code should not compile.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of different reasons.

One is to allow storing string literals in read-only memory (as others have already mentioned).

Another is to allow merging of string literals. If one program uses the same string literal in several different places, it's nice to allow (but not necessarily require) the compiler to merge them, so you get multiple pointers to the same memory, instead of each occupying a separate chunk of memory. This can also apply when two string literals aren't necessarily *identical*, but do have the same ending:

```
char *foo = "long string";
char *bar = "string";
```

In a case like this, it's possible for `bar` to be `foo+5` (if I'd counted correctly).

In either of these cases, if you allow modifying a string literal, it could modify the *other* string literal that happens to have the same contents. At the same time, there's honestly not a lot of point in mandating that either -- it's pretty uncommon to have enough string literals that you could overlap that most people probably want the compiler to run slower just to save (maybe) a few dozen bytes or so of memory.

By the time the first standard was written, there were already compilers that used all three of these techniques (and probably a few others besides). Since there was no way to describe one behavior you'd get from modifying a string literal, and nobody apparently thought it was an important capability to support, they did the obvious: said even attempting to do so led to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 12):

It's undefined behaviour to modify a literal because the standard says so. And the standard says so to allow compilers to put literals in read only memory. And it does this for a number of reasons. One of which is to allow compilers to make the optimisation of storing only one instance of a literal that is repeated many times in the source.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you ask about the reason why literals are placed in
read-only memory, not about technical details of linker doing this and
that or legal details of a standard forbidding such and such.

When modification of string literals *works*, it leads to subtle bugs
even in the absence of string merging (which we have reasons to
disallow if we decided to permit modification). When you see code like

```
char *str="Hello";
.../* some code, but str and str[...] are not modified */
printf("%s world\n", str);
```

it's a natural conclusion that you *know* what's going to be printed,
because `str` (and its content) were not modified in a particular
place, between initialization and use.

However, if string literals are writable, you *don't know it* any
more: str[0] could be overwritten later, in this code or inside a
deeply nested function call, and *when the code is run again*,

```
char *str="Hello";
```

won't guarantee anything about the content of `str` anymore. As we
expect, this initialization is implemented as moving the address known
in link time into a place for `str`. It does not check that `str`
contains "Hello" and it does not allocate a new copy of it. However,
we *understand* this code as resetting `str` to "Hello". It's hard to
overcome this natural understanding, and it's hard to reason about the
code where it is not guaranteed. When you see an expression like
`x+14`, what if you had to think about 14 being possibly overwritten
in other code, so it became 42? The same problem with strings.

That's the reason to disallow modification of string literals, both in
the standard (with no requirement to detect the failure early) and in
actual target platforms (providing the bonus of detecting potential
bugs).

I believe that many attempts to explain this thing suffer from the
worst kind of circular reasoning. The standard forbids writing to
literals because the compiler can merge strings, or they can be placed
in read-only memory. They are placed in read-only memory to catch the
violation of the standard. And it's valid to merge literals because
the standard forbids... is it a kind of explanation you asked for?

Let's look at other
languages. [Common Lisp standard](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/)
makes modification of literals undefined behaviour, even though the
history of preceding Lisps is very different with the history of C
implementations. That's because writable literals are *logically*
dangerous. Language standards and memory layouts only reflect that
fact.

Python language has exactly one place where something resembling
"writing to literals" can happen: parameter default values, and this
fact [confuses people all the time](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Your question is tagged `C++`, and I'm unsure of its current state
with respect to *implicit conversion* to non-const `char*`: if it's a
conversion, is it deprecated? I expect other answers to provide a
complete enlightenment on this point. As we talk of *other* languages
here, let me mention plain C. Here, string literals are *not* const,
and an equivalent question to ask would be *why can't I modify string
literals* (and people with more experience ask instead, *why are
string literals non-const if I can't modify them*?). However, the
reasoning above is fully applicable to C, despite this difference.

Comment: Since when does C++ care to prevent one from shooting himself in the foot? Also, why doesn't the same problem exists with raw array: `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};`?

Answer (score 1):

Because is K&R C, there was not such thing as "const".  And similarly in pre-ANSI C++.   Hence there was a lot of code which had things like `char * str = "Hello!";`   If the Standards committee made text literals const, all those programs would have no longer compiled.  So they made a compromise.  Text literals are official `const char[]`, but they have a silent implicit conversion to `char*`.

Comment: C++11 wants to have a word with you.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, string literals are `const` because you aren't allowed
to modify them.  In standard C, they would have been `const` as
well, except that when `const` was introduced into C, there was
so much code along the lines of `char* p = "somethin";` that
making them const would have broke, that it was deemed
unacceptable.  (The C++ committee chose a different solution to
this problem, with a deprecated implicit conversion which allows
the above.)

In the original C, string literals were *not* const, and were
mutable, and it was garanteed that no two string literals shared
any memory.  This was quickly realized to be a serious error,
allowing things like:

```
void
mutate(char* p)
{
    static char c = 'a';
    *p = a ++;
}
```

and in another module:

```
mutate( "hello" );  //  Can't trust what is written, can you.
```

(Some early implementations of Fortran had a similar issue,
where `F(4)` might call `F` with just about any integral value.
The Fortran committee fixed this, just like the C committee
fixed string literals in C.)