# What's wrong with my strcpy?

Tags: c++, strcpy

I tried to make `strcpy` myself. It should work, I even copied and pasted the (almost exact code) from someones post here about  `strcpy`. Both give me a "Segmentation Fault".

```
char* strcpy(char * destination, const char * source)
{
    while( (*destination++ = *source++) != '\0' ) 
        ;
    return destination;
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
char* a = "hello";
cout << strcpy(a, "Haha") << endl;
```

Comment: Show the code where you call this function.

Comment: My bet is that this being called w/ string literal as destination

Comment: Why couldn't C++03 make `char *` string literals banned as well :(

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, that was my guess too.  And OP's edit confirms.

Comment: The question is why you're even making or using `strcpy` in the first place. This is C++, plus there's already a perfectly fine one in the `cstring` header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are string literals const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const)

Comment: @chris problably because i wanna learn and don't belive in magic

Comment: When you return from strcpy `destination` points to the end of the string so even if you get rid of the segfault it won't print anything out

Comment: @Normal I don't believe in magic either, but somehow I can reconcile that with allowing myself to use standard headers...

Comment: There's nothing magic about copying bytes from one place to another.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe, It seems like a kind of pointless exercise, to be honest. Learning about C strings is fine and dandy, but best done with a [structured book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The exercises in them are meant to teach.

Comment: for all you people saying this is pointless, he has clearly learned something from this exercise. relax. I agree about the book though

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe It's great that you're trying things out, and would be better if you started with a good book. But one other thing you need to do is start paying attention to compiler warnings, and compiling your code with all warnings turned on. `char* a = "hello";` should cause a warning about a deprecated conversion to be emitted. That should've been a clue that maybe you're trying to do something illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to write to data segment since `"hello"` is stored there.

Therefore, when you call `strcpy` you get segmentation fault.

Try:

```
char a[] = "hello";
cout << strcpy(a, "Haha") << endl;
```

instead.

EDIT: Inside your `strcpy` function, after the copy, `destination` will point to end of the string, you need to return beginning of the string instead.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to overwrite a string literal.  That causes undefined behaviour.  Declare `a` as an array instead:

```
char a[] = "hello";
```

Your `strcpy` implementation has a bug, too (assuming the normal semantics).  It should return a pointer to the *beginning* of the destination buffer, not the end.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a pointer to a string literal:

```
char* a = "hello";
```

Trying to modify a string literal is undefined behavior. As Carl suggested, if you initialize an array with the string literal instead it will work:

```
char a[] = "hello" ;
```

Comment: @dmckee Yup, was in the process of doing that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Besides everything mentioned above and below about string literals, you're also returning a pointer to the **END** of your string, so even if you avoid the segmentation fault, you'll print "".