# Initialisation of pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

When I type `int * a = 10` it shows error .But when I give  `char *b = "hello"` it doesn't shows error ?

We can't initialize values directly to pointers but how it is possible only in `char`. How it is possible to allocate value in the character pointers?

Answer (score 8):

The type of `"hello"` is a `char` array, which [decays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) into a `char` pointer. You can therefore use it to initialize a variable of type `char*`.

The type of `10` is `int`. It cannot be implicitly converted to `int*` and hence `int *a = 10` is not valid. The following is perhaps the closest `int` equivalent to your `char` example:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *a = arr;
```

(There is also an issue with constness here, which I am not addressing to keep things simple. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const) if you'd like to learn more.)

Answer (score 6):

This is because `"hello"` is a **string literal** that represents an `array` of `char`. The starting address of the `array` is assigned to the pointer `b` in the assignment `char *b = "hello"`.
 `10` is a value of type `int` and cannot be assigned to a pointer of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the string literal in C++ is `char const[6]`, and `char[6]` in C (it's the number of characters in the literal, including the terminating NUL character).

While `char *b = "hello";` is legal in C, it is deprecated in C++03, and illegal in C++11. You must write `char const *b = "hello";`

The reason that works is because both languages define an implicit conversion of array types to a pointer to the first element of the array. This is commonly referred to as *decay* of the array.

No such conversion is applicable to `int *a = 10;`, so that fails in both languages.