# Why is the default char* in a parameter must be const?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
class MyString {
private:
    char *m_pchString;
    int m_nLength;
public:
    MyString(char* pchString="0") {      //problem on this parameter
        m_nLength = strlen(pchString)+1;
        m_pchString = new char[m_nLength];
        strncpy(m_pchString, pchString, m_nLength);
        m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = 0;
    }
    ~MyString() {
        delete[] m_pchString;
        m_pchString = 0;
    }
    char* GetString() {return m_pchString;}
    int GetLength() {return m_nLength;}
};
```

If I complied this, the compiler will send me a warning:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

unless I modify the parameter from `char *pchString = "0"` to `const char *pchString = "0"`

Why is the default char* in a parameter must be const?

Comment: This has nothing to do with default parameters. String literals in C++ are `const` no matter where you use them.

Comment: @Juen Khaw, you may want to change your "About me:" to `const char *chStat = "Begineer";` :)

Comment: @vsoftco, lols, u got me badly :P

Comment: [Are string literals const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493139/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because string literals like `"some string"` are immutable, and trying to modify one (you can attempt to modify them if passing via non-const reference) leads to undefined behaviour. That's why the standard C++ deprecated this conversion.

Try this for fun (but pls not in production code), live [here](http://ideone.com/dqJIbH):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char* str = "test";
    str[0] = 'w';
    std::cout << str; // oops
}
```

Related: [Why are string literals const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a string literal, such as `"0"`, it is put in the read only parts of the program. Making any changes to such data leads to undefined behavior. By trying to initialize a variable of type `char*` to a sting literal, you are allowing the possibility of the read only data to be modified. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

It's similar to:

```
const int num;
int* ptr = &num;  // Wrong
```