# difference between char str[m][n] and char *str[] when passing to function

Tags: c++, string, char

```
 1. char *names[5]={"Web","Security","Software","Hello","Language"};

 2. char names[5][30]={"Web","Security","Software","Hello","Language"};
```

what is the difference between these two ?

One I know is that (1.) first one can have desired length of string while (2.) second one can have string 29 characters with '\0'

But I am confused that what's the difference when they are passed to function and how they are passed ?

Please elaborate I am new to C++ ....

Comment: Well the first one doesn't compile because string literals are `const`.

Comment: The first one is allocating `5 * sizeof(char*)` bytes and it's storing a pointer at each index, while the second one is allocating `5 * 30` bytes and saving your strings there. P.S. That's C.

Comment: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|    It compiled but with this warning, can you please explain Quentin

Comment: It is not allowed by C++ standard to point to string literal without const. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const

Comment: @CodeLearner this is a leftover compatibility rule with an old C standard which didn't have `const`. In any case, modifying a string literal is forbidden (and will generally crash), so you're better off declaring it `const` and let the compiler catch any misuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one shouldn't compile unless you add a `const`; `const char *names[5] = ...`.

Once you fix that, the first is an array of pointers, the second is an array of arrays.

If you pass them to a function, the first will decay into a pointer to a pointer, `const char**`, while the second will decay into a pointer to an array with 30 elements, `char(*)[30]`.

That is,

```
void pointers(const char**);
void arrays(char(*)[30]);

const char *names[5]={"Web","Security","Software","Hello","Language"};
pointers(names); // Good
arrays(names); // Bad

char names[5][30]={"Web","Security","Software","Hello","Language"};
pointers(names); // Bad
arrays(names); // Good
```