# c++ How to change a character in char* in for loop

Tags: c++, char

Hey guys i got an assignment that i cant seem to solve. I get a char* string and i need to make all upper case letters (everything is in ASCII) to lower case using bit operations. I'm adding my code but it keeps crashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void convertToLower(char* string)
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
   {
       if (string[i] >= 65 && string[i] <= 90)
       {
           string[i] |= 32;
       }
   }
   cout << string << endl;
}
int main()
{
   convertToLower("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? What are you passing to it?

Comment: http://ideone.com/53laPq All fine for me. You're probably calling it by providing a string literal, don't do this. That's read-only memory.

Comment: Also make sure that your string is null-terminated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not directly related to your problem: don't use magic numbers. `65` -> `'A'`, `90` -> `'Z'` etc.

Comment: The second comment (Gill Bates) applies here.

Comment: added the main i hope this help

Comment: @Rokni yes that helped, because the problem is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this string reversal C code causing a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to modify a string literal i.e. read-only memory: that's the reason for your crash (or undefined behavior to be more precise)

```
void convertToLower(char* str)
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
   {
       if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90)
       {
           str[i] |= 32;
       }
   }
   cout << str << endl;
}

int main() {

    char arr[] = "STRING";
    convertToLower(arr); // Fine

    char *readonly = "READONLY";
    convertToLower(readonly); // Nope
}
```

I suppose a recent compiler should also have warned you of this (`Wwritable-strings`).

Read more about this issue here: [Why are string literals const?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14570993/1938163)

Comment: it works can you please send me a guide on the whole `*` meaning?

Comment: @Rokni Added a link in case you want to learn more about string literals and why they're read-only

Answer (score 2):

```
convertToLower("Hello");
```

`"Hello"` is of type `const char[]`. Conversion from `const char*` to `char*` has been illegal since C++11 so your compiler should've told you something about that if you're using a modern one, at least a warning. You can't overwrite read-only memory (`const`). Attempting to do so leads to undefined behaviour. Make a copy of it and pass that in:

```
char copy[] = "Hello";
convertToLower(copy);
```