# code do not read text from file c++

Tags: c++, fopen

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017   C++

Problem is that code do not read text that is in the file MVS point by red wave test.txt and in dialog box is written: argument of type "const char" is incompatible with parameter of type char

File is in the project folder////

//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
# include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>


void HowManyWords(char FileName[]) {
  FILE*file = fopen(FileName, "rt");
//if (!file)return false;
int count = 0;
char str[100];
while (fgets(str, 100, file)) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {

        if (str[i] >= 'A'&&str[i] <= 'Z' || str[i] >= 'a'&&str[i] <= 'z') {
            if (str[i + 1] >= 'A'&&str[i + 1] <= 'Z' || str[i + 1] >= 'a'&&str[i + 1] <= 'z') {
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}
fclose(file);
printf("%i", count);
}

int main()
 {
HowManyWords("test.txt");

printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

//111 words

Problem.

[image: problem]

Comment: in MVS2015 all is working ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are string literals const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const)

Comment: Why are you using C code in C++?

Comment: The only c++ in your code is `#include <fstream>` and it's commented out.

Comment: MSVC 2017 is a bit more standard compliant than its predecessors and providing a pointer to `const` data to a non-`const` pointer has long been verboten in standard C++ because it's dangerous as smurf. MSVC may have finally decided to close off this source of errors.

Comment: The compiler **is** telling you that you try to pass `const char` to a function expecting `char`. Do you think you can modify the function to actually expect `const char`?

Comment: BTW, you can reduce the number of comparisons by half, by using `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`

Comment: See also `std::isalpha` to test if a character is a letter.

Comment: BTW, your algorithm is not counting "words" but some kind of letter combination.  Words are usually separated by spaces or other punctuation (except maybe hyphenated words especially at line ends).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: No it isn't.

Comment: `void HowManyWords(char FileName[])` => `void HowManyWords(const char *FileName)` and for heavens sake, uncomment `//if (!file)return false;` otherwise you are racing off into *Undefined Behavior* if `fopen` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues of your program is that your function take a pointer to Mutable, R/W character array:

```
void HowManyWords(char Filename[]);
```

In the `main` function, you are passing it a *const* char string.  Text literals are constant.

If you are not changing the contents of `Filename`, pass it as "read-only":

```
void HowManyWords(char const * Filename)
```

Reading the type from right to left, this is a pointer to constant ("read only") `char`.  The function is stating that it will not change the contents of `Filename`.  Thus you can pass it a string literal.

For more information, search the internet for "c++ const correctness pointers".

**Edit 1: simple example**
Here is a simple working example showing the correct parameter syntax for your `HowManyWords` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void HowManyWords(const char Filename[])
{
    puts("Filename: ");
    puts(Filename);
    puts("\n");
}

int main()
{
    HowManyWords("test.txt");
    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compilation and output, using `g++` on Cygwin, on Windows 7:

```
$ g++ -o main.exe main.cpp

$ ./main.exe
Filename:
test.txt





$
```

As I stated above, comment out your code in `HowManyWords` and get the parameter passing working correctly.  Next, add a little bit of code; compile, test and repeat.

Comment: It still not working .I just want that it showed result in consol

Comment: Can you please send me a code that is working(fixed version of main)?

Comment: My answer should remove the compiler warning or error.  As for why your program is not working correctly, step through with a debugger.

Comment: If you are allergic to debuggers, insert some `printf` statements to display the values of variables.

Comment: You could always comment all the code in your function, compile and test.  Next, uncomment the next line.  Compile and test.  Repeat until you find the statements that are failing.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting paid enough to use debuggers for other people.

Comment: How can I debug if I even can not enter to  compile it because error in HowManyWords("test.txt"); ?

Comment: @Inex: See my latest edit.  If that is not working, you'll have open up your IDE, compile, and move to the right so I can see the *compiler or build error messages*.