# error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<char *,std::allocator<_Ty>>'

Tags: c++

I tried to compile the following codes:

```
vector<char*> art = { "a","an","the" };
```

but received error message:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<char *,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char *
1>        ]
1> note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

If i changed the element type to 'const char *' like this:

```
vector<const char*> art = { "a","an","the" };
```

it can be compiled.Can someone tell me the reason?Thanks a lot.

Comment: String literals are `const char*`, not `char*`. Reason enough?

Comment: Another variant of *"why can't I initialize a `char*` with a string literal?"*. Impressive.

Comment: String literals are read  only, it makes sense for the language to have some way of statically asserting that you're not trying to mutate one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two things going on here. First and the most basic one, is that string literals are `const` by default in C++. Shadi gave a very good link in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644935/8853275).

The second thing is that brace initialization cannot accept narrowing conversions. This is very well explained in the item 7 of Meyers' [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) book, very advisable one.

It's a matter of the type system: when you initialize a container with values within braces, like in `{ "a","an","the" };`, this braced expression is deduced to have the type `std::initializer_lists<const char *>`, which then will call the container's constructor that takes an initializer list as a parameter. But, remember that string literals have type `const char *` in C++, but you declared your vector to hold elements of type `char *`. This will imply a narrowing conversion `const char * -> char *`, which brace initialization doesn't allow. Therefore, this constructor is discarded, no other is found, and your compiler complains.

Comment: This is a great answer, but Microsoft's compiler really ought to give a more helpful message, as it doesn't indicate what type(s) the initializer list is trying and failing to match. I had to switch to gcc to work that out.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because string literals are constants and they are being stored in the read-only memory. [**Why**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const)?

if it suits you, you can alternatively use:

```
vector<string> art = { "a","an","the" };
```