# Cannot call initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++

Related to:

[why am i getting a "no instance of constructor matches the MyArray::MyArray" argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482406/why-am-i-getting-a-no-instance-of-constructor-matches-the-myarraymyarray-arg)

[why is `std::initializer_list` often passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803475/why-is-stdinitializer-list-often-passed-by-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<char *,std::allocator<_Ty>>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643960/error-c2440-initializing-cannot-convert-from-initializer-list-to-stdvec)

Why does:

```
int main()
{
    rtosc::Ports p = { // <== error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 
                       // 'rtosc::Ports'
        rParamF(foo, rLinear(-1,10), "no documentation"), // <== macro 
                                                        // expansions look ok
        rParamF(bar, rLinear(0, 100.2), "no doc"),
    };
}
```

macros expand to:

```
rtosc::Ports p = {      
    {
        "foo" "::f",
        ":" "parameter" "\0"
        ":documentation\0="
        ":" "min" "\0=" "-1" "\0"
        ":" "max" "\0=" "10" "\0"
        ":" "scale" "\0=" "linear" "\0",
        "no documentation" "\0",
        0,
        [](
            const char *msg,
            rtosc::RtData &data)
            {
                (void)msg;
                (void)data;
                rObject *obj = (rObject*)
                data.obj;
                (void)obj;
                const char *args = rtosc_argument_string(msg);
                (void)args;
                const char *loc = data.loc;
                (void)loc;
                auto prop = data.port->meta();
                (void)prop;
                if (!strcmp("", args))
                {
                    data.reply(loc, "f", obj->foo);
                }
                else
                {
                    decltype(obj->foo)
                    var = rtosc_argument(msg, 0).f;
                    if (prop["min"] && var < (decltype(var))
                        atof(prop["min"]))
                        var = (decltype(var))
                        atof(prop["min"]);
                    if (prop["max"] && var > (decltype(var))
                        atof(prop["max"]))
                        var = (decltype(var))
                        atof(prop["max"]);
                    if ((decltype(var))(obj->foo) != var)
                        data.reply("/undo_change",
                        "s" "f" "f",
                        data.loc,
                        static_cast<int>(obj->foo),
                        var);
                    obj->foo = var;
                    data.broadcast(loc, "f", obj->foo);
                }
            }
    }
};
```

gives the error message:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'rtosc::Ports'
```

Ports is a struct:

```
namespace rtosc {
    struct Ports
    {
        std::vector<Port> ports;

        Ports(std::initializer_list<Port> l);

      protected:
        void refreshMagic(void);
      private:
        //Performance hacks
        class Port_Matcher *impl;
        unsigned elms;
    }

struct Port {
    const char  *name;    //!< Pattern for messages to match
    const char  *metadata;//!< Statically accessable data about port
    const Ports *ports;   //!< Pointer to further ports
    std::function<void(msg_t, RtData&)> cb;//!< Callback for matching functions

    class MetaIterator
    {
    public:
        MetaIterator(const char *str);

        //A bit odd to return yourself, but it seems to work for this
        //context
        const MetaIterator& operator*(void) const { return *this; }
        const MetaIterator* operator->(void) const { return this; }
        bool operator==(MetaIterator a) { return title == a.title; }
        bool operator!=(MetaIterator a) { return title != a.title; }
        MetaIterator& operator++(void);
        operator bool() const;

        const char *title;
        const char *value;
    };

    class MetaContainer
    {
    public:
        MetaContainer(const char *str_);

        MetaIterator begin(void) const;
        MetaIterator end(void) const;

        MetaIterator find(const char *str) const;
        size_t length(void) const;
        //!Return the key to the value @p str, or NULL if the key is
        //!invalid or if there's no value for that key.
        const char *operator[](const char *str) const;

        const char *str_ptr;
    };

    MetaContainer meta(void) const
    {
        if (metadata && *metadata == ':')
            return MetaContainer(metadata + 1);
        else
            return MetaContainer(metadata);
    }

};
}
```

with the constructor implemented as:

```
Ports::Ports(std::initializer_list<Port> l)
    :ports(l), impl(NULL)
{
    refreshMagic();
}
```

The code looks correct; there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the macro expansion only with initializer_list but I don't see what.

Comment: That is a somewhat terrifying amount of macro code for modern C++. Are you sure that's the best approach? A lot of that can be done with C++ without all the fuss and dark magic.

Comment: It's from a dated synthesizer

Comment: Indeed, dated is the key. This looks like early 2000s code.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer with all that macro stuff out of the way, or at least expanded to what you think it is.

Comment: @tadman How can you get the full expansion of a macro if you can't build? I added a snippet in the question

Comment: You may have to expand it by hand.

Comment: Please post everything as text not images

Comment: Generate a pre-processed output file.

Comment: some compilers have option to output listing.. sure MSVC and gcc do. I used that to debug through  swamps of macrodefines

Comment: You can use `/E` or `/P file` on msvc, or `-E` on gcc/clang. I think this is it: https://godbolt.org/z/5949bf but you should manually reduce it further

Comment: @Alan Birtles. Macros can be written to a file as long as the code compiles. I'll copy it by hand. Onhover does not show the whole expanded macro.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That only works if the file compiles.

Comment: @Artyer mvsc in correct

Comment: @AlanBirtles done

Comment: You didn't specified definition of Port and that error is way of MSVC complain that it cannot actually use that list to initialize  Port.? Order? extra initializers? type mismatch of elements? gcc would say something like  "could not convert ... from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'rtosc::Ports'"

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie Added Port definition

Comment: unless `msg_t` is not `const char*`, I don't see what's the problem.while 0 instead of nullptr is odd  it should be fine.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie   typedef const char *msg_t; . I've formatted the expanded macro and removed one entry. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Elliott Code formatted.

Comment: msvc 19 compiles the simplified version of code  *throws things arounds*

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie Got it build; there was one extra field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is the way of MSVC complain that it cannot actually convert that list to initialize `Port` with given initializer list, which means type mismatch and lack of available conversion between members of type and members of list.