# C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I've been coding a dll and it is almost finished, the final issue I have is this. Argument list consists of: (const char [23], const char [23], const char [21], const char [24], const char [24], const char [24], const char [24], const char [17], const char [42]) The above error displayed at this place in my code...

```
   std::vector<char*> monitors = { //messages to look out for.  Might as well grab everything fairfight related
    "XiteNetworkGet1Message",
    "XiteNetworkGet2Message",
    "XiteNetworkGoMessage",
    "XiteNetworkInfo1Message",
    "XiteNetworkInfo2Message",
    "XiteNetworkInfo3Message",
    "XiteNetworkInfo4Message",
    "XiteNetworkPush1",
    "ScreenshotNetworkRequestScreenshotMessage"
};
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead?

Comment: Those char pointers are [const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570993/why-are-string-literals-const). So you need to use `vector<const char*>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are not modifiable, and therefore cannot be stored as `char*`.  You can use `const char*` instead:

```
std::vector<const char*> monitors = { ... };
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments section, you could consider `std::vector<std::string>`.  That would be preferable if there is no special need to store these literals as pointers.  Usually there is no such need.

Comment: For storing a bunch of literals, `std::vector<std::string_view>` is the way to go. No need for any dynamic allocation here.